# No requests are being made from Google Play Store deployed app

Tags: ionic-framework, https, android-security

I have made an app in Ionic and published it in closed beta in Google Play Store. Https requests work very well when testing it with "ionic serve" or "ionic run android" but no request is being done if I install the app from Google Play Store. What can be the problem?

Update: also, requests are being done when I install on the phone the debug apk. After signing it and zipaligning it, it no longer works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While it is allowed in debug mode to make untrusted https requests via "ionic run" or "ionic serve" commands, once the app is upload to Google Play Store those requests don't succeed by default. A trusted certificate is needed in the backend.